# Push notification Ionic Not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

[image]

The Device Token Is Not Pushing Into The Ionic dashboard.
I Think most of the all Things Correctly. 
But Am stuck With this Portion.
After only Getting the  Device token we can push The notification message.
Please Help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yea i have Found a Solution With My Own Node server. Ionic Push Is Not worked for me.

Comment: Could you please guide me on a work around...

Comment: @Pavitar Please got through with this http://www.sitepoint.com/push-notifications-in-ionic-apps-with-google-cloud-messaging/ I Resolved the issue doing the same in the article.